# Solving PDEs using Taylor series

Tags: differential-equations, series-expansion

I'm thinking of solving a Partial differential algebraic equation using multidimensional polynomial (i.e. Taylor series). Consider the PDAE:

$$\mathbf F \left( \mathbf x, \mathbf y, \frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_j}, \frac{\partial^2 y_i}{\partial x_j \partial x_n}, \ldots \right) = \mathbf 0 \, , \left\{1<i<m,1<j<n\right\} \, ,\tag{1}$$

with a boundary/initial condition of

$$\mathbf G \left( \mathbf y, \frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_j}, \frac{\partial^2 y_i}{\partial x_j \partial x_n}, \ldots \right)_{\partial \Omega} = \mathbf 0 \, . \tag{2}$$

Now if we approximate $ \mathbf y$ with a multidimensional polynomial:

$$ y_i \approx \sum_{l_1=0}^{o_1} \ldots \sum_{l_n=0}^{o_n} a_{i\left(l_1, \ldots, l_n\right)}x_1^{l_1} \ldots x_n^{l_n} \, ,  \tag{3}$$

and substitute it in Eq. 1 , we get system of nonlinear equations of $a_{i\left(l_1, \ldots, l_n\right)}$s. Using the boundary conditions this system of nonlinear equations can be solved to find $a$s.

I want to write a Matematica macro to automate this process.

- Where should I start?
- Are there any example about that?
- Has there ever been an attempt to do so? even with other symbolic CAS software

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Something like `AsymptoticDSolveValue`? Read this [mathematica blog post](http://blog.wolfram.com/2018/07/19/getting-to-the-point-asymptotic-expansions-in-the-wolfram-language/)

Comment: @rhermans awesome. exactly. let me check this out and come back here.

Comment: @rhermans I'm gonna try it on [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/166310/solving-navier-stokes-equations-for-a-steady-state-compressible-viscous-flow-in) which I want to finally solve and then post a new question if I had any issues. as far as this question matters I think I have found a solution to work on.

Comment: Realted [177120](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/177120/10397) [168064](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/168064/10397) [25363](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25363/10397).

Comment: @rhermans ok, I took a look and the first issue is that it seems the function is only for ODEs. I could not find any examples of PDAEs.

Comment: I suggest that you show the due diligence in your question. [Edit] and explain how/why the related questions and the documentation for `AsymptoticDSolveValue` do not answer your need.

Comment: @rhermans I posted a follow up question [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/95886/algorithm-for-using-power-series-to-numerically-solve-a-partial-differential-equ) . I would appreciate if you could take a look.